# Displaying multiple tables depending on data available

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to display data from multiple tables on one page but I need to do different queries to get all the people to show up. How do I format a query where it will select data from the job/jobSearch table if there is data that matches with the studentID from the student and major tables or select from the education table if there is data that matches the studentID. Both job/jobSearch and the education tables will not have data for the same student at the same time because they will either be choosing that they are employed after graduation or continuing their education so if they choose education they skip the questions regarding employment and vice versa.

```
<?php

include('includes/db_connect.php');
//include('student.php');

$query_student="SELECT *
                FROM student
                JOIN major
                ON student.studentID=major.studentID
                JOIN jobSearch
                ON major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID
                JOIN job
                ON jobSearch.studentID=job.studentID
                JOIN education
                ON job.studentID=education.studentId";
    $result_student=mysqli_query($conn, $query_student) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

echo '<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Graduate Year</th>
        <th>Major</th>
        <th>Activity After Graduation</th>
    </tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_student))
{
    echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
        echo '<td>' . $row['firstName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['lastName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['gradDate'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $row['major'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['activity'] . '</td>';
    echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
}
echo '</table>';

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Would be better if you provided sample table data and schemas. But I suspect you can achieve what you want with union statements provided the result columns from the different tables are the same.

Comment: Basically I will have students who are employed showing up as

John | Doe | 2016 | Computer Science | Employed

and another student who is studying still show up as 

Jane | Dae | 2016 | Stats | Graduate School

I am going to add more columns later giving more information about their post grad activity but "Employed" and "Graduate School" are located in different tables - "job" and "education"

Comment: If you have students showing up more than once in your result set you can use distinct to filter out the duplicates.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you need is "LEFT JOIN" For example, `SELECT * FROM student LEFT JOIN major ON student.studentID=major.studentID LEFT JOIN jobSearch
                ON major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID LEFT JOIN job
                ON jobSearch.studentID=job.studentID LEFT JOIN education
                ON job.studentID=education.studentId WHERE job.description="Software Engineer" and education.major="Computer Science"` You can add more filter in WHERE clause. This query should give you ALL students with matching filter - education, job, etc. Adjust your filter AND or OR.